# How do I create this parallax effect

Tags: javascript, css-animations, parallax

I am trying to create a parallax scrolling effect where some images will be scrolled a bit fister than other element does.

here is the example after hero section there is some image which scroll bit fast - https://mushroomgroup.com/live-entertainment/

My code so far

```
function parallax() {
  var small_left_imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".overlaping-left-image");

  for (let i = 0; i < small_left_imgs.length; i++) {
    let div = small_left_imgs[i];

    if (isInViewport(div)) {
      // The element is in the visible viewport
      console.log("Element is in view");

      var yPos = 50 - window.pageYOffset / 25 + "%";
      div.style.top = yPos;
    } else {
      // The element is not currently in the visible viewport
      console.log("Element is out of view");
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
  parallax();
});

function isInViewport(element) {
  var bounding = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}
```

Comment: those effects are basically animate on scroll effect. you can achieve that using any animation library. I would like to suggest you check out this https://www.framer.com/motion/